# Why is yesterday different that now - 24 hours?

Tags: php

Just curious if anyone knows the source well enough for a quick answer.

```
date("[D M d H:i:s Y]", strtotime("now - 24 hours"))
```

prints out: [Tue Oct 24 18:07:56 2017]

```
date("[D M d H:i:s Y]", strtotime("yesterday"))
```

prints out: [Tue Oct 24 00:00:00 2017]

I get the semantics of why yesterday is referencing a date where now - 24 hours refers to a datetime. I guess I'm more curious about why they wouldn't yesterday be a macro for now - 24 hours and how the source handles it.

Comment: because `yesterday` was a whole day while `now - 24 hours` was an exact point in time.

Comment: `00:00:00` is a time too. It's the beginning of the day.

Comment: Because time is not yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the function calls with "yesterday" and "now" do not refer to time but to declaration. This has something to do with [DAMP](https://codeshelter.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/dry-and-damp-principles-when-developing-and-unit-testing/) code:

"Yesterday" is a reference to the question: "When was yesterday?" -> "Yesterday is Tuesday October 24th 2017 which begins at 00:00:00".

00:00:00 is time 0, the start of the day. We commonly know it as 12:00 in the clock. But it's really 0. There's nothing else above 11:59:59 P.M. In the other format it's 23:59:59 hours. There doesn't exists 24:00. It's 00:00.

"Now" - 24 hours is a different reference: "This time, right now subtracted by 24 hours is... Yesterday at this time."